# Keeping track how many signals are called?

Tags: c, signals

I created a program where a signal call installs a new signal handler 'signum' and basically display a message whenever a terminal special char is pressed, such as CRTL-C.

I was wondering what if I wanted to keep track how many times CRTL-C was pressed? How can I go about implementing that? Thank you.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <signal.h>

main() {
    void    f(int);     
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    signal( SIGINT, f );        

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {       
        printf("...I am waiting for you...\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

void f(int signum) {    
    printf("Haha, you clicked me!\n");
}
```

Comment: Calling `printf` in a signal handler is unsafe -- if a signal is delivered in the middle of another I/O call (such as the `printf` in your main loop) it may crash or otherwise misbehave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static variable:

```
void f(int signum) {
   static int cnt = 0;
   printf('Hahah, you clicked me %d time(s)!', ++cnt);
}
```

If you want that count available elsewhere, then use a global variable instead.